# color halftone using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have trouble to make color halftone image using matlab with error diffusion method which is the original input image is decomposed to three colors (cyan, magenta, and yellow) and then each color will be transformed into halftone image like [this picture](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/839/v0c6.jpg/).

I've been searching and i found jarvis error diffusion method for grayscale image :

```
function outImg = jarvisHalftone(inImg)
inImg = double(inImg);
[M,N] = size(inImg);
T = 127.5;
y = inImg;
error = 0;
y= [127.5*ones(M,2) y 127.5*ones(M,2) ; 127.5*ones(2,N+4)];
z = y;

for rows = 1:M
for cols = 3:N+2
z(rows,cols) =255*(y(rows,cols)>=T);
error = -z(rows,cols) + y(rows,cols);

y(rows,cols+2) = 5/48 * error + y(rows,cols+2);
y(rows,cols+1) = 7/48 * error + y(rows,cols+1);

y(rows+1,cols+2) = 3/48 * error + y(rows+1,cols+2);
y(rows+1,cols+1) = 5/48 * error + y(rows+1,cols+1);
y(rows+1,cols+0) = 7/48 * error + y(rows+1,cols+0);
y(rows+1,cols-1) = 5/48 * error + y(rows+1,cols-1);
y(rows+1,cols-2) = 3/48 * error + y(rows+1,cols-2);

y(rows+2,cols+2) = 1/48 * error + y(rows+2,cols+2);
y(rows+2,cols+1) = 3/48 * error + y(rows+2,cols+1);
y(rows+2,cols+0) = 5/48 * error + y(rows+2,cols+0);
y(rows+2,cols-1) = 3/48 * error + y(rows+2,cols-1);
y(rows+2,cols-2) = 1/48 * error + y(rows+2,cols-2);

end
end

outImg = z(1:M,3:N+2);
outImg = im2bw(uint8(outImg));
```

But it didn't work for color image. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the halftoning image toolbox from http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~bevans/projects/halftoning/toolbox/

In general however, halftoning is done one color plane at a time.  In the case of screen halftoning, you would generally have a screen per color.  However, in your case it seems like you want an FM screen, in which case you may use the same algorithm per color plane.

Assuming your jarvisHalftone routine works for a grayscale image, then you can create a color halftoning method using using something like:

```
function outImg = jarvisColorHalftone(inImg)
[N,M,P] = size(inImg);
outImg = logical(zeros([N,M,P]));
for p = 1:P
  outImg(:,:,p) = jarvisHalftone(inImg(:,:,p));
```