# Color halftone with MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

How to color halftone using MATLAB code ?

I first used jarvis black and white half tone then modified it color halftone.

My approach :-

```
function outImg = jarvisColorHalftone(inImg)
[N,M,P] = size(inImg);
outImg = logical(zeros([N,M,P]));
for p = 1:P
  outImg(:,:,p) = jarvisHalftone(inImg(:,:,p));
end
outImg;
```

The function above is not working.

```
// jarvisHalftone function for grayscale to black and white image
function outImg = jarvisHalftone(inImg)
inImg = double(inImg);

[M,N] = size(inImg);
T = 127.5;
y = inImg;
error = 0;

y= [127.5*ones(M,2) y 127.5*ones(M,2) ; 127.5*ones(2,N+4)];
z = y;

for rows = 1:M  
for cols = 3:N+2
z(rows,cols) =255*(y(rows,cols)>=T);
error = -z(rows,cols) + y(rows,cols);

y(rows,cols+2) = 5/48 * error + y(rows,cols+2);
y(rows,cols+1) = 7/48 * error + y(rows,cols+1);

y(rows+1,cols+2) = 3/48 * error + y(rows+1,cols+2);
y(rows+1,cols+1) = 5/48 * error + y(rows+1,cols+1);
y(rows+1,cols+0) = 7/48 * error + y(rows+1,cols+0);
y(rows+1,cols-1) = 5/48 * error + y(rows+1,cols-1);
y(rows+1,cols-2) = 3/48 * error + y(rows+1,cols-2);

y(rows+2,cols+2) = 1/48 * error + y(rows+2,cols+2);
y(rows+2,cols+1) = 3/48 * error + y(rows+2,cols+1);
y(rows+2,cols+0) = 5/48 * error + y(rows+2,cols+0);
y(rows+2,cols-1) = 3/48 * error + y(rows+2,cols-1);
y(rows+2,cols-2) = 1/48 * error + y(rows+2,cols-2);
end
end

outImg = z(1:M,3:N+2);
outImg = im2bw(uint8(outImg));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [color halftone using matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935520/color-halftone-using-matlab).

Comment: Clarify your error and see if the duplicate question solves your issue